# pip/pip3 failing "AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'chunked'"

Tags: python, pip, attributeerror

I'm trying to install pandas on my computer (running Arch), and I get this message every time I use pip (or pip 3)

```
pip3 install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 318, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 218, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 164, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 572, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 530, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 675, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 793, in _get_page
    return _get_html_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 144, in _get_html_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 473, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 396, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 461, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 53, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 437, in send
    return self.build_response(request, resp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 107, in build_response
    if response.chunked:
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'chunked'
```

I've reinstalled pip, pip3 and restarted my computer but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: try `sudo pip3 install pandas`. For me, usual pip doesn't working with permissions reason

Comment: @TheZadok42 may be pip is not installed in your system

Comment: The error stack let think that you have request and cache control installed. Can you build a virtual environement (or a special installation) without them and try it again?

Comment: https://github.com/ionrock/cachecontrol/issues/137

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by using pip as root. This is the solution:

```
sudo pacman -S python-requests
```

Afterward, you should use pip like this:

```
pip install _something_ --user
```

Or just

```
sudo pacman -S _something_
```